# Rename [aladdin-disney] to [aladdin-1992]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We now have [aladdin-2019](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aladdin-2019), but we've got a lot of [potential tag confusion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/218689/revisions) with [aladdin-disney](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aladdin-disney) (which is now vague). For the sake of clarity and consistency, we should rename the tag to [aladdin-1992]

It might not be a bad idea to also make [aladdin-disney] a synonym of the 1992 tag.

Comment: Seems like someone has gone ahead and done this, when there’s only a couple of questions you might as well do it yourself rather than making a meta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have retagged the three questions about the film, and transferred the tag description to the new tag.